# My css should be applying but it's ignored for some reason

Tags: css, google-cloud-platform, svelte, svelte-3

This is only the component that is rendering the text that says "Forbidden" which is because I hit my GCP quota.

```
<script>
    export let text;
    export let color;
</script>

<pre class="formatted" style="--color: {color}">{text}</pre>

<style>
    .formatted {
        border-left-width: 6px;
        border-left-color: var(--color);
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
</style>
```

[The generated HTML and CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHxcO.png)

I looked in the box model and it shows that the border is 0 but when I click on it to change it, it shows what it's supposed to be.
[The rendered page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsApp.png)

Comment: You need to define border-style too, because by default it is "none", so you have a non-existing border of 6 pixels... just use border-style:solid , but there are other styles to play with if you wish

Comment: If I understand correctly you cannot render the color saved in variable ?
1- one possible issue maybe you do not define variable correctly :

Try this :

```
<style>
  :root {
    --color-red: red;
  }

    .formatted {
      border-left: 6px solid var(--color-red);
    }
</style>
```